# C++ Compiler background of construting objects

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-construction

For example I have line of code:

EDITED:

```
MyClass myObject = MyClass(5);
```

Here, the constructor of MyClass MyClass() will be called. It take the parameter and does what suposed..
But I this example myObject is not a reference - it is an actual object. So how the compiler do this:
construct an object by MyClass constructor, which does not know the location of actual object
(by saying location I mean address in RAM on stack).
Same question applies also to other examples (myObject = new MyClass(5);, myobject(5), etc.)

EDIT
1) Why `MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);`
This is actually equivalent to: `MyClass myObject(i);`
2) Is in this case "=" is operator= (overloaded)?
3) Can you please write an equivalent code to compiler generated operations?
4) What role copy-constructor acts here (`MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);`)?

Comment: This won't compile since `myObject` doesn't have a type, and your c'tor call is malformed. If you were being idiomatic you'd write `MyClass myObject(i);`.

Comment: This code is illegal. So is the code in your list of other examples. Perhaps you mean `int i = 0; MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);` , or something. The details are actually important here.  Please go back to your compiler and check that the code you are posting about is actually the code you compiled

Comment: After your edit your code is still invalid. I'm not sure what your question is either. The compiler knows what to do because there's a standard and it's in control of where and when it allocates things.

Comment: Sorry, but this is basic stuff. Google _copy constructor_. Then once you grasp that, _move constructor_. Then keep reading.

Comment: So may I ask what exactly is invalid?
Also, I am posting this question with hope to get professional answer about compiler features and assembly. For example answer might be on operator= or etc., but I am still asking because I want to know how it actually behaves.

Comment: I am not interested now in those basics what is what and how to write code. I am interested in architecture and background.

Comment: The compiler knows exactly where the object is located at runtime. The compiler knows where everything is.

Comment: "compiler features and assembly", "architecture and background" are not mandated by the Standard; all that is required is a certain outcome of observable behaviour for given input code. Reference documentation will explain what that behaviour is and probably suggest typical ways to implement it. For anything else, tell your compiler to output the ASM and read it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass myObject = MyClass( int i );
```

This is a syntax error, an illegal mixture of declaration and use. You probably meant:

```
int i = 42;
MyClass myObject = MyClass( i );
```

This is actually equivalent(*) to:

```
MyClass myObject( i );
```

This declares a `MyClass` object with local scope ("on the stack"), and then initializes the memory using the `MyClass` constructor.

```
myObject = new MyClass(int i);
```

Again, this is an invalid mix of declaration and use syntax. You probably meant:

```
int i = 42;
MyClass * myObject = new MyClass( i );
```

This allocates dynamic storage ("on the heap") and constructs a `MyClass` object there.

A pointer to that memory / object is then assigned to `myObject`, which is of type *pointer* to `MyClass`.

---

In both cases, the constructor initializes a `MyClass` object at {*some memory location*}. Which location that is depends on the context in which the constructor is called. The compiler knows that context, and knows (how to obtain) the memory address at runtime.

---

---

Answering the added questions (which, actually, should be separate questions):

> 1) Why `MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);` This is actually equivalent to: `MyClass myObject(i);`

This **looks** like a constructor call creating a temporary `MyClass` object which is then assigned (`operator=()`) to `myObject`.

But it is not, because that would be just stupid.

Since `myObject` -- the object assigned to -- is *created* by this statement, and the temporary would not *exist* after this statement, the C++ standard allows the "temporary" `MyClass` object to be created *in place of `myObject`* by the constructor(*), avoiding the duplicate effort of construction / assignment / destruction of the temporary.

(A mechanic that C++11 expanded to *any* kind of temporaries, in a way, with the advent of the "move" semantics and `&&` rvalue references.)

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass( int i ) : member( i ) { std::cout << "const\n"; }
        ~MyClass() { std::cout << "dest\n"; }
        MyClass & operator=( MyClass const & other ) { std::cout << "assign\n"; }

    private:
        int member;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass x = MyClass(42);
}
```

This will print:

```
const
dest
```

There is *no* assignment.

> 2) Is in this case "=" is operator= (overloaded)?

No. As I said, that specific statement is equivalent to `MyClass myObject( i )` -- no assignment taking place, just in-place construction.

> 3) Can you please write an equivalent code to compiler generated operations?

I don't think you will learn much by looking at disassembly. And anyway, your compiler is better at that than I am. (Or you are.)

> 4) What role copy-constructor acts here (MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);)?

What *role*? I have no idea what you mean.

---

---

(*): As rici correctly pointed out, the [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) making this equivalent is only *legal* if a visible copy / move constructor exists.

Comment: All that being said, there *is* a time and place for learning the fine print and details of all this, but judging from your question, I'd suspect that you should stick to "it just works" for now. Learn the proper syntax, just *use* what the language is giving you. First learn to *drive* a car, and what a "clutch" and a "gearbox" actually *does*, before trying to understand how they actually *work*. No offense intended, but you are in driving school right now; don't try to dismantle everything. ;-)

Comment: I was so missunderstood. I am working with embedded systems for couple of years now. Also, I am studying ARM architecture and software toolchain specifications and features at deep level. I have very strong background in C progr. and now I am into C++. When I have free time I try to understand it a lot deeper than just "it just works". I hate when people's attitude is like this. I really hate it. My question was far more deeper than this answer by DevSolar. My mistake was hurying  to post and not to check that I have done that simple stupid mistake in code, which lead this disccusion to this.

Comment: @KarolisMilieška: Then please improve your question, so I can improve my answer. As it stands, it is difficult to tell what you want to know, beyond what I have written in my answer. I hate that attitude, I really hate it, when people don't bother to write a *good* question, and then complain if a *good* answer to their *bad* question doesn't satisfy because my crystal ball reading skills failed to correctly judge your experience, skill set, *and actual question*.

Comment: @KarolisMilieška: Amended the answer.

Comment: @DevSolar - I don't understand why you call `MyClass( int i )` a *copy* constructor instead of a regular constructor - [copy constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) take a reference to another fully instantiated object of the same type and copies it, and usually would have the syntax eg `MyClass( const MyClass& src)`.

Comment: @antiduh: Yes... a nasty habit I picked up I-don't-know-where, mentally dividing constructors into default - copy - more-than-one-parameter. :-( Will edit that out.

Comment: @DevSolar: `MyClass myObject = MyClass(i);` is not *quite* equivalent to `MyClass myObject(i);`. They both end up doing the same thing, thanks to copy elision, but the first one will not compile unless there is either a public copy or move constructor. (Because you can't elide an illegal copy.)

Comment: @rici: The OP's post *started* with the former, so I took that context as a given.

Comment: @DevSolar: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d25c36cfb53a00b  (C++14: 12.8/32, see the note at the end of the paragraph). (And fair enough given the context of the question. But answers are not always read in that context.)

Comment: @rici: I know I've seen this before, but I have to pick up the old Sutter again to refresh my memory. :-D Maintenance coding gives you a good eye for errors, but erodes your grasp of the fine print...